# slide children ul of parent from left to right jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that contains a menu, that menu slide from left to rigth when the user click on a button, everything is ok until here, but i can't replied the same effect when I tried to show the next target.

The skeleton of the menu is below:

```
<button id="icons-header" class="hamburguer">
 Push me!
</button>
<div id="sideBar" class="container-fluid sidebar visible">
<div class="row">
    <div class="menu-left">
            <ul id="mm-1" class="mm-list visible"> /This is the principal menu
                <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#women">Women</a></li>
                <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#men">Men</a></li>
                <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#kids">Kids</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- from here to the final are the sub elements -->
            <ul id="men" class="mm-list">
                <li><a class="mm-next icon" href="#" data-target="#mm-1">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>  Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-title"><span> Men</span></li>
                <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#men-clothing">clothes</a></li>
                <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#mm-bags">stuff</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="men-clothing" class="mm-list">
                <li><a class="men-bags" href="#" data-target="#men">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>  Men</a></li>
                <li class="menu-title"><span> clothes</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">element</a></li>

            </ul>
```

The first effect to show the menu is this:

```
var hidden = $('#sideBar');
        var element = $('#mm-1');
        if ((hidden.hasClass('visible')) && (element.hasClass('visible'))){
            hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');

        } else {
            hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');

        }
```

That code I replied to show the new segment but not works, my complete code is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y1n8m3py/20/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@victor, In this case you can do something like this(I just made changes in JS). Please take a look at once.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(".hamburguer").click(function(){
  var button =  $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(typeof button);
    if(button == "hamburguer")
    {
        $(this).removeClass('hamburguer');
        $(this).addClass('blueCross');
        $('#mm-1').show();
        /*$('#sideBar').show(300);*/
    }else
    {
        $(this).removeClass('blueCross');
        $(this).addClass('hamburguer');
        $(".mm-list").hide();
    }
    var hidden = $('#sideBar');
    var element = $('#mm-1');
    if ((hidden.hasClass('visible')) && (element.hasClass('visible'))){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');

    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
        $('#mm-1').show();
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '.mm-next', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var hidden = $('#sideBar');
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    var others = $("div.menu-left").find(".mm-list").not(target);
    others.hide();
    hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    $(target).show();
    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I check that you add new class called .sub_sidebar I think this class needs to put it on each sub-element that i want to slide, really?

Comment: @victor, No, Not at all. That's only for my testing, You do not have to add any extra class. Please take a look at updated code.

Comment: It works, thank you but i have a question? it is possible to only make the slide for the `ul` element?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I am not about `ul` can be animate or not. Glad to know my answer is being helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code, You class name is different in you javascript. I have made some changes in your javascript please take a look into it and let me know if it doesn't work

```
$(function(){
$(".hamburguer").click(function(){
        var button =  $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(typeof button);
        if(button == "hamburguer")
        {
            $(this).removeClass('hamburguer');
            $(this).addClass('blueCross');
            $('#mm-1').show();
            /*$('#sideBar').show(300);*/

        }else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('blueCross');
            $(this).addClass('hamburguer');
            $(".mm-list").hide();

        }
        var hidden = $('#sideBar');
        var element = $('#mm-1');
        if ((hidden.hasClass('visible')) && (element.hasClass('visible'))){
            hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');

        } else {
            hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');

        }


    });
    $(document).on('click', '.mm-next', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data("target");
        var others = $("div.menu-left").find(".mm-list").not(target);
        others.hide();
        $(target).show();

        return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: the elements show after second click when the div is hidding

Comment: Everythings is working fine, can you elaborate in more detail?

Comment: yes of course, actually when user clicked on the button, the container div slide from left to right to show  a menu, if the user click on Men, Woman or Kids, show a submenu but now the effect is only show and hide and i want that effect was not show or hide I want to slide from left to right

Comment: You can see the effect in uk.tommy.com and you can check it on responsive mode, the div slide and when you click on the first elements slide and show the next list but I want to avoid slide all the container just only the `ul` tag

Answer (score 0):

Class name 'hamburguer' create issue as they seems non-identical in supplied javascript. Please check it once. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I paste again the code, but the correct is the code that is in the jsfiddle

Comment: @victor as per my understanding, you want a menu like, when user click on menu link it should animate left to right and same effect when click to home link. right?